# monacaバックエンドのコレクションに登録したアイテムの個数は表示されても、詳細が取得されません。

Tags: javascript, monaca

```
var Place = monaca.cloud.Collection("place");
var Criteria = Place.find('name == "Monaca"', {propertyNames: ["title", "body"], limit: 5});
Place.find(Criteria, "_createdAt DESC", {propertyNames: ["title", "body"], limit: 5})
.done(function(result)
{
   console.log('Total items found: ' + result.totalItems);
   console.log('Total items found: ' + result.items[0].body);
})
.fail(function(err)
{
   console.log("Err#" + err.code +": " + err.message);
})
});
```

monaca Docsのコードを書いて自分の環境に合わせ書いただけなのですが、
totalItemsの個数は取得できたものの、その下に書いた
result.items[0].bodyがundefindになってしまいます。
エラーも出ていないのでどこがおかしいのかがわかりません。
他に何かプロパティを書かなければいけないのでしょうか...

Answer (score 0):

自分で実行できていないため、予測での回答となりますが
resultsは配列なので

```
console.log('Total items found: ' + result.items[0].body);
```

の部分を

```
console.log('Total items found: ' + result[0].items[0].body);
```

に変更することで取得できると思います。

Comment: 文を変更してみたらエラーが発生して動きませんでした...

Comment: お力になれず申し訳ありません。発生したエラーコードを記載して頂ければ私以外の方からも回答を頂けるかもしれません。

Comment: console.log('Total items found: ' + result[0].items[0].body);

Comment: いえ回答していただいてうれしかったです！！エラーの内容はconsole.log('Total items found: ' + result[0].items[0].body);と打ったのにもかかわらずTotal items found:の文字列すらコンソールに表示されませんでした...

Comment: 実行環境はiOSでしょうか。Androidだとエラーが表示される可能性があります。また、そもそもデータが取得できているかわからないのでconsole.log(JSON.stringify(results));を実行して、resultsを確認してみるとよいと思います。

Comment: Androidです。resultで取得できたので、今度はresult.item[0]でコレクションのアイテムの_(アンダーバー)の付いている情報まで取得できました！！でも自分で設定した'name'がしゅとくできていないません。monacaのコレクションのアイテムはresult.item[0].bodyで取得できるとmonacadocsに書いてあったのですが取得できませんでした。bodyではないのでしょうか...

Comment: コンソールログに表示したオブジェクトの中身を参考に、目的の要素を指定してはいかがでしょうか